# Is 'irreasonable' as the opposite of reasonable acceptable or not?

Tags: differences, is-it-a-word

Generally, the negative form of 'reasonable' is 'unreasonable' with the negative prefix 'un', but I do have come across 'irreasonable' used as the opposite of 'reasonable'. So my question is whether both are acceptable by native speakers of English in communication?

Comment: Depending on your intended meaning either "unreasonable" or "irrational" would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The term "irreasonable" is not acceptable to **well-educated** native English speakers.

As evidence:

1. it's not in the Oxford English Dictionary - which is the ultimate arbiter of "good English"; and
2. automated spell checks (for instance, in Microsoft Word and even in this text box on StackExchange) mark the spelling as incorrect.

The term "irreasonable" is clearly capable of being understood, and a quick Google search shows the term is occasionally used.

However, any person using the term would convey the impression that he or she is either a non-native speaker or a poorly-educated native speaker.

Comment: Many thanks TechnoCat. Your answer is quite clear. It's good to me and other readers potentially with the same confusion.

Comment: The OED is certainly not the "arbiter of good English". It is a *descriptive*, *historical* dictionary which aims to record usage, not to prescribe it. For example, it includes words like "irregardless" and "conniption", but it does have usage labels for them, namely "in nonstandard or humorous use" and "U.S. vulgar". But even that isn't saying that the OED disapproves of the words -- it it trying to record how they are used.